# Set Default value of BOOL type to YES

Tags: ios, objective-c

From Initializing, the default value of `BOOL` type is `NO`, Is it possible to change the value to`YES` when it is synthesized.

Such that its value assigned alternatively by next time.

Comment: Isn't that what your init method is for?

Comment: `#define YES (BOOL)0` :) 
`#define NO  (BOOL)1` as bydefault instance is filled with 0

Comment: @BuntyMadan Please don't do that! That would make for a terrible debugging session...

Comment: @SimonM Yeah that why it's just comment otherwise Accepted Answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
-(id)init{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
       //This is where you are supposed to initialise anythin you need

       xyz = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BOOL myVar;

@property BOOL myVar;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 myVar=True;
}
```

Comment: Your example creates/sets a global variable called `myVar`, not the `@property`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in viewDidLoad method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    xyz = YES;
}
```

Comment: viewDidLoad (and viewDidUnload) can be called multiple times in the life cycle of a UIViewController. This is dangerous advice.

Comment: @grahamparks please give some example to support what you said. i am curious.

Comment: Yes i also wanna know about it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**in .h file**

```
BOOL flag;
```

**in .m file**

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        flag = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no default value if you write

```
-(void)somemethod {
  BOOL x; //no default value
  }
```

now x has no default value and  will be initialized to NO as instance is filled with 0 on init.
  so anthor way need to do when init. like

`-(id)init{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
       x = YES;
    }
}`

or some on `ViewDidLoad`
 `x = YES;`

Comment: Your `BOOL x` in `-somemethod` will not be initialised to `NO`, it will be contain whatever garbage data is on the stack when the method is called.

Comment: @一二三 thanks but as i learned `x` will `init` to 0. have some important reference related to this.

Comment: Only `static` variables and instance variables will have their storage zero'd.